# Recording the ArcPy script execution method

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, windows-scheduler

I have composed an ArcPy script which is run via a windows scheduler.The same script is loaded into a script tool so a user can run the process manually. I've used: get parameters as text, with or's and not's, to hard-wire the standard variables, if they are not speicifed.

```
ReportFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
if ReportFolder == '#' or not ReportFolder:
    ReportFolder = "C:\\Data\\GIS"
```

The process runs and during so writes to a text file log, for example:

```
txtFile.write("=    For ArcGIS 10.3.1: Date: "+str(timed)),txtFile.write ('\n')
```

I'd like to record **what method** was used to execute the script; was it via the *windows scheduler*, or by the *script tool*, or by a *python client* like PyScripter.

Is anyone aware of some form of os environment thingy that can be called by ArcPy?

Comment: I think [so] may be a better place to look for help on Python's `os` module.  You would not need to call it from ArcPy, just to use it in a script that was also using the `arcpy` module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest use parameter passing to the script while you call this script using task scheduler and grab this parameter using **[sys](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html)** module- as below

```
try:
    data = "=    For ArcGIS 10.3.1: Date: "+str(timed)+ sys.argv[1]+'\n'  #grab parameters passed
except:
    data = "=    For ArcGIS 10.3.1: Date: "+str(timed)+ "Arcgis tool used"+'\n'  # else arcgis tool used to run
```

And passing parameters to script in task scheduler is easy just add space and pass string ( like "test") as below-

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

Along a different line of thinking:

```
import os
ComputerName =os.getenv('COMPUTERNAME')
txtFile.write("=    Run By: "+str(ComputerName)),txtFile.write ('\n')
```